# Присвоение текста в innerHTML у объекта модифицирует сам текст

Tags: javascript, html

**Код**

```js
tmpHTML = `<div class="question toleft">
    <div class="question-body">
        Где котлеты?
    </div>

    <form class="question-answer" id="answer-field-0" data-type="text">
        <input data-type="text" type="text" class="answer-field maximized" placeholder="Ваш ответ">
        <input id="answer-submit-0" type="submit" class="submit-button unactive" value="ААА">
    </form>
</div>`

console.log(tmpHTML);

questions_list_el.innerHTML = tmpHTML;

console.log(questions_list_el.innerHTML);
```

**Что выводит консоль**

Первый console.log()

```html
<div class="question toleft">
                <div class="question-body">
                    КОТЛЕТЫ
                </div>

                <form class="question-answer" id="answer-field-0" data-type="text">
                    <input data-type="text" type="text" class="answer-field maximized" placeholder="Ваш ответ">
                    <input id="answer-submit-0" type="submit" class="submit-button unactive" value="Завершить">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Второй console.log()

```html
<div class="question toleft">
                <div class="question-body">
                    КОТЛЕТЫ
                </div>

                
                    <input data-type="text" type="text" class="answer-field maximized" placeholder="Ваш ответ">
                    <input id="answer-submit-0" type="submit" class="submit-button unactive" value="Завершить">
                
            </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конце тега input дробь: `<input class=".." />` вместо `<input class="..">`

Comment: не помогло......

Comment: именно в конце тега

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузер не позволяет создавать вложенные формы, так как это бессмысленно с точки зрения поведения форм. Вы вставляете `innerHTML` в элемент, который находится внутри тега `form` или сам является формой. Поэтому браузер вычищает форму из Вашего html-а.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html

> There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element
> can't be nested.

Comment: спасли! спасибо вам огромное!